# How to use Bash globbing in combination with the brace expansion (in sort)?

Tags: bash, sort

I use `sort` to remove duplicate lines from text files, sort in alphabetical order, [overwriting the files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29244408/6404709) (`{,}` in the command):

```
sort -u -o $HOME/Documents/notes/URLs.txt{,}
```

How to add  additional files to the mix, after `URLs.txt`? To illustrate with three additional ones:

```
$HOME/Documents/notes/{URLs.txt,Android.txt,mpv.txt,firefox.txt}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sort` is sorting once all the input. So anytime we provide more than one file arguments to `sort`, we sort the concatenation of them. To sort separately the files and rewrite each one with the output, you have to invoke separate commands.

```
for f in URLs.txt Android.txt mpv.txt firefox.txt
do
    sort -u -o "$HOME/Documents/notes/$f"{,}
done
```

while this:

```
sort -u -o newfile "$HOME"/Documents/notes/*.txt
```

would sort the concatenation of all input files to newfile.

Answer (score 0):

In `zsh`, I'd do:

```
for f (~/Documents/notes/(URLs|Android|mpv|firefox).txt(N)) sort -uo $f $f
```

(or `sort -uo $f{,}` if you want to golf it).

A `bash` equivalent would look like:

```
(shopt -s extglob nullglob
  for f in ~/Documents/notes/@(URLs|Android|mpv|firefox).txt; do
    sort -uo "$f" "$f"
  done
)
```

Those using globbing rather that brace expansion, so would only process those `URLs.txt`...`firefox.txt` if they actually exist.

With `zsh`, you can also add the `.` glob qualifier so that those files are processed only if they are *regular* files. With `bash`, you could add `[[ -f $f && ! -L $f ]] || continue` in the loop to skip the non-regular files.